# Protecting Sub folder using .htaccess and .htpasswd in PHP/Html

Tags: php, .htaccess, passwords

In my website having sub folder, so I trying to protect that folder files using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd`.

- Root Folder
- Root Files

  - Sub Folder
  - Sub Folder Files
  - .htaccess
  - .htpasswd

-- Root Files

**.htaccess code looks like below**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile ./.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And **.htpasswd code looks like below**

`test:pass@word1`

When I enter the http://10.10.10.11/website/subfolder/test.html it's prompted the password, I entered but it's throwing error. See below image.

Video of Screenshot:
[image]
Please suggest to do this.

Comment: inside .htpasswd put this username:pass@word1 not test:pass@word1 - convert password in hashkey

Comment: You need to configure `.htaccess` for your subfolder

Comment: protecting from what?

Comment: An internal server error _after_ you have been prompted for the credentials usually means, that the path to the .htpasswd file was not correct. Is your “Root Folder” the actual server file system root - or just the “root” you have access to using your FTP or SSH account? If the path specified for the `AuthUserFile` is not absolute, it will be treated as relative to what is set as [`ServerRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot)

Comment: @GiacomoM, If open any page of subfolder files, needs to authenticate.

Comment: @ChandanKumar, I have changed to username:pass@word1. Still same error. In this case what is the username? username or any other name? I mean optional

Comment: u can generate hashkey and put there using command -> openssl passwd -apr1 pass@word1

Comment: @ChandanKumar I'm new bie. If I write `openssl passwd -apr1 pass@word1` this in `.htpasswd`. What is the username and password?

Comment: username is username and password is pass@word1, please decode password in hashkey using given oppenssl command

Comment: @ChandanKumar Yes I have updated `.htpasswd` file with username:$apr1$h81U4v3.$8Msypa0Kx2hQ/C0948BuV1. Still getting same error.

Comment: Whts ur apache version?

Comment: @ChandanKumar Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.6

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile ./.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

If you don't want to use online password generator, you could use openssl

```
openssl passwd -apr1 pass@word1
```

Then put the generated password to .htpasswd with format:

username:
Example:

.htpasswd

```
username:$apr1$h81U4v3.$8Msypa0Kx2hQ/C0948BuV1
```

Comment: copy .htpasswd and paste in ur .htpasswd file.

Comment: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.6